# Mouseover Folder Preview for Windows 10 Desktop

Tags: windows-10

I recently reset my Windows 10 computer and I'm trying to keep my desktop less cluttered.  Let me tell you, it's not easy!  So many things would like to be conveniently launched from the desktop, but the grid system makes it nearly impossible to find what you're looking for after the shortcuts pile up...

Therefore, I'd like to sort, for example, all my graphic-design related links into one folder, all my gaming links into another, etc.  Then, I'd like to be able to view a panel of these links by moving the mouse over that folder for a second, and then click whichever appropriate link.

Is there software, preferably free, that works on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at Fences by Stardock. It should be exactly what you need. If you like all your applications, documents, graphics, gaming applications, etc. This will provide a layout for you to organize all of that and more in its own container in a very easy and clean looking interface. It works great with Windows 10 as well as Windows 7 & 8. Instead of having things in a folder - you would have the applications in each container.

## [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) (commercial)

> Fences is a one-of-a-kind program, allowing you to draw labeled shaded areas on your desktop, which become movable and resizable containers for your desktop icons. These groups can help bring organization and consistency to your computers desktop, solving the "constant mess" problem that has plagued the desktop since its inception. Fences also helps you finally appreciate the wallpaper you have hiding behind all that clutter. In addition to its organizing features, Fences offers a novel quick-hide feature (in-patenting-process). Double click your desktop, and all your icons will fade out.
>
> #### Key Features
>
> - Use fences on modern, high DPI monitors.
> - Create shaded areas to organize your desktop.
> - Blur the wallpaper behind fences on Windows 10.
> - Roll up fences to the Title-bar for cleaner desktops.
> - Double click the desktop to hide or show icons.
> - Define rules to organize your desktop icons.
> - Swipe between multiple pages of fences.
> - Create a desktop portal from any folder.
> - Navigate the folder structure from within the fence.
> - Windows 10 compatibility.
>
> [image: screenshot of Fences in action]

Comment: $50?  No sirreee!

Comment: @Menasheh I believe you were confused on the pricing structure, it's $50 for pretty much all of Stardock's programs and only $10 (FYI there are coupons out for these applications too) for Fences.

Comment: @Menasheh, Fences had free (partially limited) version for non-commercial use few years ago. I used it on WinXP. Try to find older versions. Hope licence change doesn't spread into the past?

Comment: @Qwertiy unfortunately, I'm not aware of a free version ever existing.